# jQuery: name of jquery object as string?

Tags: jquery, object, selector

i wrote a function that takes a string as input.

```
function ajaxLoad(targetBox, loadUrl) {
   $("div." + targetBox).css("opacity",0.25);
}
```

so normally i call this function like this.
`ajaxLoad("commentListBox", "some url");`

However right now, i have the problem that I need to pass a object i retrieve via a parent selector. so this is not a string but an object.

```
var box = $(this).parent().parent().toString();
ajaxLoad(box, "some url"); // is a syntax error
```

How can I handle this?

if i `console.log(box);`it says [OBJECT]

Comment: That is not a _syntax_ error.

Comment: yeah right, sorry. `Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .[object Object]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `class`, try:

```
var box = $(this).parent().parent()[0].className;
ajaxLoad(box, "some url");
```

If `Id`, try:

```
function ajaxLoad(targetBox, loadUrl) {
   $("div#" + targetBox).css("opacity",0.25);
}

var box = $(this).parent().parent()[0].id;
ajaxLoad(box, "some url");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the type of 'targetBox' and handle it differently if it's an object:

```
function ajaxLoad(targetBox, loadUrl) {
    if(typeof(targetBox) == "string")
       $("div." + targetBox).css("opacity",0.25);
    if(typeof(targetBox) == "object")
       $(targetBox).first().css("opacity",0.25);
}
```

*Note:  the '.first()' acts as a safety precaution in case your object references multiple elements.*

Answer (score 0):

javascript variables are not typed, so it will work. However, if you want to change the type of the parameters, then you are liable to need a separate function. It depends what property of box you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

Could you modify your function somewhat to handle the passing of an object to it?

So, if you check what type the targetBox is and handle it appropriately:

```
function ajaxLoad(targetBox, loadUrl) {
   var el = "";

   if(typeof(targetBox) === "object") el = targetBox;
   else el = "div." + targetBox;

   $(el).css("opacity",0.25);
}
```

and then when you call the function, simply pass in the element:

```
var box = $(this).parent().parent();
ajaxLoad(box, "some url");
```

---

Bonus, use a shorthand if for smaller code:

```
function ajaxLoad(targetBox, loadUrl) {
   var el = typeof(targetBox) === "object" ? targetBox : "div." + targetBox;
   $(el).css("opacity",0.25);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a class name in the selector, you would get the class name from element:

```
var box = $(this).parent().parent().attr('className');
```

However, it's really a detour to get the class name from the element just to find the element again. You can make the function work with both a class name and a jQuery object:

```
function ajaxLoad(targetBox, loadUrl) {
  if (typeof targetBox !== 'object') targetBox = $("div." + targetBox);
  targetBox.css("opacity", "0.25");
}
```

Usage:

```
ajaxLoad($(this).parent().parent(), "some url");
```

If you only use the function for this, you can just skip the first line in the functon to make it only accept a jQUery object.

Note: You should use the string `"0.25"` rather than the number `0.25` when you set the opacity style. The number will be converted to a string, and with some locales it will be converted to `"0,25"` instead of `"0.25"`.